# What does "I'm so sorry for you to hear that" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Suppose you witnessed someone hearing something unpleasant, and you want to express sympathy for them.

Can we say

> "I'm so sorry for you to hear that"

?

It it grammatical and natural?

I guess we could also say:

> I'm so sorry that you heard that (it occurred just a while ago that you heard that)

Or

> I'm so sorry that you have to hear that. (Does this mean something different?)

Comment: 1) means that someone was saying something bad about  you that you were not supposed to hear and did.

Comment: What is the context this sentence is being use.  Who said it? To whom? What does "that" refer to?

Comment: @JamesK "that" is referring to the news like something Bruce Becker wrote in his answer. By the way, does my sentence sound natural?

Comment: Perhaps it would be more common to write *I'm so sorry you **had** to hear that*, but there's nothing wrong with it as it is.

Comment: @JasonBassford I've got some answers from two native speakers that my sentence isn't grammatically correct and doesn't make any sense, even given the context. I'd like to hear your comment on it.

Comment: @Floret Unless there is a particular reason *why* they think it's ungrammatical, I can't respond. Them simply not liking it isn't a good reason. At best, it just means it's not a construction *they* would use, which is a commentary on style, not grammar.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Yes, they're just saying it's ungrammaical, giving no reasons. Anyways, do you think that my sentence is grammatical and does make sense unlike them?

Comment: @Floret As I've already said, it's grammatical and it makes sense. It's up to *them* to raise a particular point of concern if they have one.

Comment: @Jason Bassford Can my sentence mean either **"I'm so sorry that you heard that"** or  **"I'm so sorry that you had to hear that"** according to context?

Comment: @Floret Your sentence says nothing about obligation. It could be taken to mean that, but that assumption wouldn't be based on the words themselves. Although there is a difference between the two phrases you mentioned, in practical terms, people would interpret them to mean the same thing.

Comment: There is a huge difference between: to be sorry **for** someone and to **be sorry [that] someone [verb] + that**. When you use **for**, it can no longer have the meaning it does **without for**. Please see my answer. I just do not think this is very complicated...

Comment: @Jim Reynolds Thank you very much for your consideration on my question :). But not to worry about it anymore! I already resolved what is the problem that makes me interpret the sentence incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us assume that there are three people: Jack, Bob and Claire. Bob says to Claire: "By the way, your dog died". Jack, Claire's friend, says to Claire, "I'm so sorry for you to hear that."

Hearing that your dog died is a painful thing to hear for Claire. Jack empathises with Claire and wants to express his sympathy for her pain, so he says "I'm sorry for you to hear that" -- it is an expression of empathy.

So, both 1. and 2. are close, but should include the idea of expressing empathy.

Comment: But I really doubt whether my sentence sounds natural.

Comment: A bit of punctuation might help: "I'm so sorry, for you to hear that". A few extra words might also make it should more natural: "I'm so sorry for you to have had to hear that". "have had" because the thing happened at a moment in time in the past relative to when the person is speaking.

Comment: I just heard from a native speaker that my sentence doesn't make any sense and just ungrammaical, even given your context. I don't know why..

Comment: @BruceBecker Adding a comma there would not be a good idea. You could use a dash or ellipses, however.

Comment: Since this is a spoken phrase, this would be, in y opinion, a matter of style. However ellipsis implies that something is omitted. Nothing is omitted here, the speaker is linking two concepts "I am sorry" and "you heard that". That calls for a comma.

Comment: Regardless of the existence of a comma, native speakers seem to think of the sentence as non-idiomatic and ungrammaical. I have no idea why. It seems to be too hard even for native speakers to explain since they haven't given any clear answers on it, just saying ungrammaical, non-idiomatic.

Comment: @BruceBecker Ellipses do not only mean that something is omitted. They are *also* used to indicate pauses in speech. From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ellipsis): "marks or a mark (such as … ) indicating an omission (as of words) or a pause."

Comment: In English, "I'm sorry for you" means something very specific. And it is most definitely not the same as "I'm sorry you heard that". "I'm sorry for you. I'm sorry your dog died." OK. "I'm sorry for you to [verb] " is not grammatical in English. "I'm sorry to see you go." That is.

Answer (score 2):

1) I'm so sorry (that) you heard that (it occurred just a while ago that you heard that).
1) **Someone hears something they were not meant to hear. Past Tense.**

2) I'm so sorry (that) you have to hear that.
2) **I'm telling you now you are doing a poor job. I am so sorry you have to hear that. Present Tense**

**Neither of those can be expressed as: I'm sorry *for you* etc.**

**To be sorry for someone** means **to pity them**.

So, the only way to pity someone if they hear something they should not while using the preposition for would be to say:

**I'm sorry for you as or because you heard that or have to hear that or had to hear that**.

It is not usually what one might say.

Comment: I think *I'm so sorry for you to hear that/to have had to hear that* are also grammatical. In a real-life conversation, for example, I think most native speakers would accept them without noticing anything odd. Your examples with the that- clauses would undoubtedly be preferred style in high registers and in writing.

Comment: @JimReynolds "I sorry for you to hear that" is simply not: I'm sorry that you heard that. "I'm sorry for you" means I pity you in English. "I'm sorry you had to hear that.". As written, it is not grammatical in English.